# Rest or stretch following a fall?

Tags: injury

Having just learned to ride a bike in my 30s, I've just taken my first tumble over the handlebars and jarred my shoulder.

Should I rest the shoulder or keep stretching it? Looking to reduce recovery time

Comment: Please see a competent doctor to qualify the level of your injury.   Maybe wait a couple days, but if its still not right after 3-5 days then get it looked at.    I didn't once, after a lifting injury and 3 months later the damage was permanent..

Comment: In the immediate post-crash moments **REST**  Don't get up and walk around unless you're in immediate danger (ie, lying in the roadway)  Reason is adrenaline kicks in and you may not be aware of the damage.   Get your breath back, sip water and calm your heartrate.   Look for damage to yourself then your helmet, last your bike and gear.  Depending on what happened your bike might be fine, or brifters knocked, wheels may be untrue, or more structural damage.    Push the bike about and look for rubs/noises.  TEST THE BRAKES before riding off.  Decide if you're going onwards or going home.

Comment: This has been backed up by local pharmacy, so now sitting  in the doctors!